# Oracle NUMBER data type max limit with & without decimal points

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

I have a number field in the application which passes a numeric value to my Oracle procedure which is of NUMBER datatype. The numeric value can be positive, negative, with or without decimal points.

I need to restrict it from the application so I need to specify the maximum limit without any round-off. Can I please know what will be the limits for positive, negative, with, and without decimals points.

Comment: [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78). Shouldn't your application  be defining the valid value range though; based on business logic, with the database column restricted to match?

Comment: There is no valid value as such for the particular case. The number can be of any length and it needs to be restricted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really a range that is allowed, but a precision. You can pass any number with up to 38 digits, no matter if or where the decimal separator.

### Okay:

```
+12345678901234567890123456789012345678
-12345678901234567890123456789012345678
+1.2345678901234567890123456789012345678
-1234567890123456789012345678901234567.8
```

### May get slightly mutilated:

```
+123456789012345678901234567890123456789
-123456789012345678901234567890123456789
+1.23456789012345678901234567890123456789
-1234567890123456789012345678901234567.89
```

Demo with some longer numbers: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aa74ef09157dcf86daa76507e868fe49